# Converting a java variable into a javascript variable

Tags: jsp

This is all done in a JSP page. 
I'd like to get the Java variable "A12" to be passed in a JS variable also called "A12" which i'd like to display in a graph (which needs to be parsed into a double). The end goal is to get productive_sum1-12 to display in the graph.
[Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfaIq.jpg)
Edit: forgot to include script tags/minor modifications

```
<script>


        <%
        double productive_sum12 = 0;
        int count12 = 0;
        double average12 = 0;
        for (Guest guest : guests) {
            if (guest.getHours() == "12") {
                productive_sum12 += Double.parseDouble(guest.getProductivity());
                count12 ++;
            }
        }
         average12  = productive_sum12/count12;


        %>

var A12 = '<%= average12 %>';
data: [20, 44 ,11, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, A12],
</script>
```

Comment: Last two lines should be: `var A12 = '<%=A12%>';
data: [20, 44 ,11, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, <%=A12%>]` - no?

Comment: I changed the var <%A12%> to <%=A12%>, my mistake. But the value of A12 gets outputted as NaN. in both instances. I also forgot to mention that this is javascript.

Comment: If it's NaN it means that `count12` never gets incremented ;)

Comment: That seems to be it, Guest is a list which contains Hours, and Productivity, I can get it to show up just fine by using the code below. However it doesnt seem like i'm currently using guest.getHours, any ideas?          
             <% for (Guest guest : guests) { %>
                <li> <%=guest%>  </li> <%
            } %>

Comment: Seems like it's getting output just fine, the expected hours are showing up.

Comment: String-comparison is done with `.equals()` not `==`. Try `if ("12".equals(guest.getHours())) {...`

Comment: That "data:" line should probably be a JavaScript `var` declaration; as it is, it's a labelled statement that does not do anything.